Sampling from a hypersphere subject to a linear constraint?
I'm running into efficiency issues when trying to sample from a "hypercone" using rejection sampling. By a hypercone, I mean the set of vectors $C_{v,\beta} = \{w \sim N(0,1)\ |\ w^T v \geq \beta ,\ w^Tw = 1 \}$. Here, $v$ is the "axis" of the hypercone and $\beta$ is related to the opening angle $\theta$, since $\theta = 2\arccos(\beta)$.
What I've Tried

Sample from the unit hypersphere by drawing $w\sim N(0,1)$
If $w^Tv \geq \beta$, accept the point, otherwise reject
Repeat as needed

The issue is that when $\theta$ becomes small and the dimension $d$ becomes large, the vast majority of points are rejected, since $w^T v \approx 0$ when $d \gg 1$.
Question: Is there an efficient way of sampling from this distribution, ideally one that doesn't rely on rejection sampling?

This is a uniform distribution.  It is preserved under any equal-area projection and converted to a tractable one (Beta I expected) even under simple projections such as a cylindrical projection.  The standard example comes from Archimedes, who observed that the cylindrical projection (radially outward from the sphere's axis to an enclosing cylinder) is an equal-area projection in $\mathbb R^3.$  Generalize that.
